# How to inject script locally in firefox add-on

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have published a add-on in mozilla add-on website, it got rejected because of remote scripts.

`lib/Main.js`:

```js
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var _workers = [];
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "some url",
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    contentScriptFile: data.url("./inject.js"),
    contentStyleFile:  data.url("style.css"),
    attachTo: 'top'   
});
```

`data/inject.js`:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/javascript";
script1.src =    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);

var script2 = document.createElement('script');
script2.type = "text/javascript";
script2.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js";
document.body.appendChild(script2);

var script3 = document.createElement('script');
script3.type = "text/javascript";
script3.src = "resource://addon-id/addon-name/data/popup.js";
document.body.appendChild(script3);
```

Please help me to insert these scripts to the web content or insert these scripts locally from my addon.
And what is remote script?

Comment: I'm pretty sure these are allowed i thought in the PageMod obj you would put these paths in your `include` like `include: ['...googleapis...', '...googleapis...']` im not too familiar with sdk but this is how i thought it was.

Comment: This include says that when http://google.com is loaded, inject the inject.js script but am also not sure of including googleapis.

Comment: Mozilla amo team rejected and sent a mail  saying: 1) resources/addon-name/data/inject.js
We don't allow add-ons to use remote scripts because they create serious security vulnerabilities. We also need to review all of your add-on code, and this makes it much more difficult. Please insert those scripts locally from your add-on code.

Comment: Interesting, lets wait for an addon sdk devuser to reply they have more experience with this

Answer (score 0):

All the code you use should be reviewable and immutable, `google.com` being controlled by a suspicious company, is not trustworthy, and can replace `jquery.min.js` with password/credit card collector, without Mozilla noticing.

To avoid suspicion, copy files required to your plugin's directory, and use them as:

```js
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.mozilla.org",
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery.min.js"),
                      data.url("jquery-ui.js"),
                      data.url("popup.js")]
});
```

See [page-mod manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod), it has all needed instructions.