# Firefox add-on show popup from injected script

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a Firefox extension. I have injected some HTML button code into a webpage using a content script.  Now I want to open a popup when that button is clicked. I have a popup.html file. I want to open this file as a popup window. However, when I attempt to do so it shows the error :

> Error: Access to 'resource://test/data/popup/popup.html' from script
>   denied

my package.json:

```
{
  "title": "First",
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Just for testing",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Bharath",
  "engines": {
      "firefox": ">=38.0a1",
      "fennec": ">=38.0a1"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

injected script:

```
var popupURL = '';
var timerId = setInterval(function () {
    if(!!$('.aic').length){
        window.clearInterval(timerId);

        $('.aic').append('<div id="sendButtonID" class="sendButtonCls" role="button" tabindex="0" gh="cm" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">Send Now</div></div>');
        $('#sendButtonID').click(function(){
            console.log('Received url: ', popupURL);
            window.open(popupURL, "Popup window", 'width=400 height=500');
        });
    }
}, 1000);

document.addEventListener('popUrlEvent', function (e) {
    popupURL=e.detail;
    console.log('Received url: ', popupURL);
});
```

content.js:

```
var popupUrl = '';

var buttonCss = document.createElement('link');
buttonCss.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
buttonCss.setAttribute("type", "text/css");

var jqueryURL = document.createElement('script');
jqueryURL.type = "text/javascript";


var injectedURL = document.createElement('script');
injectedURL.type = "text/javascript";


self.port.on("init", function(scriptURLS) {

    popupUrl = scriptURLS.popupUrl;

    buttonCss.href = scriptURLS.buttonCss;
    (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(buttonCss);

    jqueryURL.src = scriptURLS.jQuery;
    (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(jqueryURL);


    injectedURL.src = scriptURLS.injectedJs;
    (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(injectedURL);
    console.log('URLS: ',scriptURLS);
});

injectedURL.onload = function(){
    var evt=document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
    evt.initCustomEvent("popUrlEvent", true, true, popupUrl);
    document.dispatchEvent(evt);
};
```

index.js:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

var urls = {
    'jQuery': data.url("js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"),
    'injectedJs' : data.url("js/main.js"),
    'buttonCss' : data.url("css/button.css"),
    'popupUrl' : data.url("popup/popup.html")
};

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "https://mail.google.com/*",
    contentScriptFile: data.url("js/content.js"),
    contentScriptWhen: 'end',
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.port.emit("init", urls);
    } 
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504534/how-to-inject-script-locally-in-firefox-add-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using add-on sdk, use "sdk/panel" in the index.js script.
    Documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel

```
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "https://mail.google.com/*",
    contentScriptFile: data.url("js/content.js"),
    contentScriptWhen: 'end',
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.port.emit("init", urls);
        worker.port.on("showpopup", function() {
            require("sdk/panel").Panel({
                contentURL: data.url("./popup/popup.html"),
                contentScriptFile: ["./lib/jquery.js",
                    data.url("js/main.js")
                    ]         
            });
        });
    } 
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to open window instead of panel ?

Comment: not sure what you mean, please visit: [link]( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel), which has examples that might fit your need